# java - checking file content before uploading to server

Tags: java, javascript

i have got a situation now.

I need to develop a webpage where user can select a file to upload and before uploading the file to server i need to check first few lines of the file whether the data is valid or not and if the data is valid then upload the file, if not through an error message.

the file will be text file.

thanks,

Sandeep

Comment: How do you upload? From a web page?n If so, how should java check the file if you're running a Java server backend and you want to check the file before uploading it?

Comment: "i have got a situation now."  Uh-huh.  Did you also have a question, or were you just sharing that with us?

Answer (score 4):

HTML/Javascript does not offer a way of reading the contents of a local file. You must either upload it and check it in the server.

If you really want a client side check, you then must build a signed applet(or even ActiveX) to run in your webpage and handle the upload instead of using plain HTML.

Comment: No... this place is for help with doubts, not for doing your job for you. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your validation on the server side, right before you perform the upload.

Comment: without uploading to server how to have a server-side validation... ??? please help me out...